# Using a bootstrap modal inside a php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a foreach loop that looks like this

```
foreach ($results as $rows)
       {
       echo
       "<tr>
         <td>" . $rows['Client_Code'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['firstname'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['lastname'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Service_Name'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Physical_Address'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Cell'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['billingemail'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $rows['Business_Name'] . "</td>
       </tr>";
     }
```

I want to set $row['Client'] so that I can open a modal on click.

In my html the modal works fine and can be called from a button like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary block btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#iconModal">Launch Modal</button>
```

Any help on this or even just a link would be helpful, I have searched around, but I can't really find a solution to this

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: um... sorry I thought what I wanted to do made sense. I am not sure how to set the link on the $rows['Client_Code']

Comment: `<td><button ...>" . $rows['Client_Code'] . "</button></td>` ?

Comment: If I do this:

<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary block btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#iconModal">" . $rows['Client_Code'] . "</button></td>

My code is hashed out from the "#iconModal"